# .NET Regex using look behind/ahead

Tags: c#, regex

why does this regex fail to match:

```
(?<="Title" = "8:)[^"]*(?=")
```

this:

```
"ARPHELPTELEPHONE" = "8:"
"ARPHELPLINK" = "8:"
"Title" = "8:something"
"Subject" = "8:"
"ARPCONTACT" = "8:something"
"Keywords" = "8:"
```

Its in excerpt from a visual studio setup project. It matches in the online tool i'm using but it doesn't match using Regex.Match()

Here's the code:

```
var productTitleRegex = @"(?<=""Title"" = ""8:)[^""]*(?="")";
var titleMatch = Regex.Match(content, productTitleRegex);
```

titleMatch.Success if false and value returns nothing

EDIT:

Maybe I'm just missing something when using Look ahead and look behind in .net regex? Because if I remove the lookarounds, this works but it matches the whole line, which I don't want. So I used lookarounds to just match the value I want.

Anyone else had a similar experience when using lookarounds in .net regex?

Comment: I tested same with C# in VS2008

Comment: right sorry, my bad. I was using the wrong input file all along :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your regex pattern with C# in VS2008, it found a match with "something" as value. looks like it is working fine. I also tested it with free tool downloaded from http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

[image]

However It won't work if your using RegEX with RegexOptions "IgnorePatternWhitespace"

```
    var productTitleRegex = @"(?<=""Title"" = ""8:)[^""]*(?="")";
    var titleMatch = Regex.Match(content, productTitleRegex, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

in this case you won't get any match